# Is a desktop PC power supply an inductive or a resistive load?

Tags: power-supply, power, resistors, power-electronics, inductive

Our daily computers' (desktop PC, server, or normal laptop, mobile chargers) power supplies:

[image]

Are those power supplies inductive or resistive loads?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are a mostly resistive load in that the AC voltage is converted to DC, then is used to drive a switching power supply. The transformer it uses is isolated from the AC input.

There is an initial surge of current as the supply switch's ON as it charges up capacitors, but quickly settles down to whatever its load demands.

Really, it is a dynamic load that is not inductive but not resistive either. An increase in AC supply voltage may show a decrease in current as the supply only draws the wattage it needs. If the AC voltage drops low it will pull more amps to maintain the voltage(s) it puts out. You *could* say it acts like an intelligent resistor as it varies by load and line voltage to keep the power to the load steady.

As long as the load is steady it behaves like a constant wattage supply.

Answer (score 3):

PC power supplies are [switched-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply). This would create enormous noise on the power lines, so something called [Power Factor Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor#Power_factor_correction_(PFC)_in_non-linear_loads) is used.

Active PFC uses some sensing to simulate a resistive load: it monitors voltage, and draws current as much as possible in phase and proportional to the voltage. It's not perfect, but it does change the equivalent load from *"awful noise injector"* to *"some kind of weird resistor"*

Comment: Filtering is what counteracts the noise, not PFC. PFC corrects the power factor, as the name implies.